# ansible suddenly gives syntax error when running sql files

Tags: postgresql, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible role which runs the few queries from an sql file

```yaml
- name: sample query
  postgresql_query:
    db: test_db
    path_to_script: /tmp/test.sql
```

And the file contains (I have just added one query to show where it is failing )

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT FROM pg_roles  
                   WHERE  rolname = 'my_user') THEN

      CREATE USER myuser NOLOGIN;
      GRANT CONNECT on DATABSE myDataBase to myuser;
      GRANT USAGE ON SCHEAMA myschema to myuser;
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

It used to work well but suddenly I started getting syntax issue  `" ansible postgresql_query unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near \"$$\begin\"`

The same untouched file used to work but now has stopped. I run this from a remote machine where ansible and other installation is controlled by an admin.

Are there any changes in ansible settings or version that could explain this? If so, how can I force `postgress_query` to treat my multiple line query as a single one (something like `setSingleline=false`)?

Comment: Simple question: you are looking for a change on ansible side. But did you upgrade or change postgres configuration since it stopped working ?

Comment: no I am using  built in client from asnible postgress_query, amd my server is remote server and no  up grade to the server

Comment: Well in this case did you try to downgrade ansible to the version you were previously using to see if ig fixes the issue?

Comment: no, I dont a have option to controlle ansible install/upgrade,  everything was done by admin.. and I get a virtual link for the playbook command .. As per admin no upgrade by them but not sure about any auto upgrade

Comment: Well then pass the problem to you admins if they don't want to give you the necessary accesses to debug it. I don't know what a "virtual link" is, but that sounds like something I never want to encounter. Or.... you can debug that on your own on your local machine using a couple of docker containers. And in this case you have all the control you want.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can confirm Ansible 2.9.10 is fine, switching to Ansible 2.10.5 throws the above error.

Answer (score 1):

Using `postgresql_db` instead of `postgresql_query` worked out for ansible>3.

Working solution for ansible>3:

```
- postgresql_db:
    db: "your-db"
    state: restore
    ...
    target: "/path/to/script-containing-dollar-quotes.sql"
```

Working solution for ansible<3:

```
- postgresql_query:
    db: "your-db"
    ...
    path_to_script: "/path/to/script-containing-dollar-quotes.sql"
```